# iCarousel scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, icarousel

How to scroll in a specific item or index, for example: I set an `NSInteger` on another `UIView` then pass it to my `iCarousel`.
In my other `UIView` I set the `NSInteger` like this:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:button.tag
                                           forKey:@"integer"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

When scrolling I use this :

```
[carousel scrollByNumberOfItems:-35 duration:10.7550f];
```

how to pass the integer to the carousel, to make it scroll then stop it to that specific item or index.

Comment: For those of us who have never seen iCarousel before, it's open source on github:  http://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)scrollToItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index animated:(BOOL)animated;`
```

Clearly stated and described in the [README](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel). First method under **methods**

Or, if you prefer:

```
- (void)scrollToItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index 
                   duration:(NSTimeInterval)scrollDuration;`
```

Answer (score 0):

in your `ViewDidLoad method` in your `Viewcontroller`....

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //configure carousel
    carousel.type=iCarouselTypeCylinder;
    carousel.autoscroll=0.4;
}
```

Comment: it scroll only to left . is there any fix to auto scroll to right?